# How to make Y.io's global events broadcast across instances

Tags: io, yui

I would like to listen for all io request in all my web pages, however, when I used the syntax below, I can ONLY listen for the io with the yui instance.

Y.on('io:success', myCallBack);

How can I write a custom method/event or something else to achieve this?

My question is actually the same as below URL:

http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=26009

I googled for a while but did not find a practical answer for this, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(Y.io._map['io:0'] || new Y.IO()).publish({
    'io:success': { broadcast: 2 },
    'io:complete': { broadcast: 2 },
    etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks much! But would you mind give me a practical example? Since I am not familiar with YUI API yet.

Comment: Well, the primary use case of YUI 3 involves keeping your code sandboxed, inaccessible to the global environment.  So communicating across instances is either not done, or done through other custom events published on Y that are configured with `broadcast: 2`. Those events would then be fired from IO event subscribers inside the sandbox. If you don't need/want sandboxing, use simpleyui, or `var Y = YUI().use(…);` to expose the YUI instance globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>io.jsp</title>
<script src="/spring-test/scripts/yui_3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
test

<script>

YUI().use("io-base", function(Y){

    function onSuccess(transactionid,response,arguments){
        alert('start!');
    }
    Y.Global.on('io:start',onSuccess);

});

Y1 = YUI().use("io-base", "node", function(Y1){

    Y1.publish('io:start',{broadcast : 2});
    Y1.io("http://www.yahoo.com.hk");   

});

</script>
</body>
```

Finally I got one example , however it works only on FF, Chrome but fail in IE:

Please suggest if there is any improvement, thanks.

Comment: I searched the api again and it seems that there is no way to achieve this without adding the Y.publish in each instance.